# Android Permissions at Run Time with fragments

Tags: android, android-mapview, android-6.0-marshmallow, runtime-permissions

I have in my project an activity that has two fragments in the xml (main):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.fragments.MainActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.google.android.gms.maps.MapFragment" />

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        class="com.example.list" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

So like you can see, one of them is map fragment.
the problem is when `setContentView()` is running, app crashes above API 23.
I tried doing (location) permissions checks before `setContentView()`, using the [documantation](http://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting.html) and the app still crashes.
Any idea?

Comment: You don't need any permission to display the map. You only need permission if you are accessing the user's location. Post your activity code.

Comment: thanks Jyotman Singh, your answer made me understand what I had missing..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your code in this way:

```
<fragment
    android:id="@+id/map"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"/>
```